# Invoking generic method with wildcards does not compile

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, java-7

Could someone explain why the following code fragmnent does not compile?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] integers = {3, 5, 8};
        Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(integers));

        Double[] doubles = {3.5, 5.5, 8.5};
        Set<Double> s2 = new HashSet<Double>(Arrays.asList(doubles));

        Set<Number> res1 = union(s1, s1);       // ->it does not compile 
        Set<Number> res2 = union(s1, s2);       // ->it does not compile
    }

    static <E> Set<E> union(Set<? extends E> s1, Set<? extends E> s2)
    {
        Set<E> result = new HashSet<E>(s1);
        result.addAll(s2);
        return result;
    }

}
```

I have read the error messages:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Integer> to Set<Number>  Main.java   /TestingGenerics/src/com/al/testinggenerics line 17 Java Problem

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Number&Comparable<?>> to Set<Number> Main.java   /TestingGenerics/src/com/al/testinggenerics line 18 Java Problem
```

What causes the problem as long as `Integer` and `Double` extend from `Number`?

Comment: In fact, @user3580294 has given the answer: The type inference of Java 7 simply was not smart enough to involve the *target type* in its type resolution. This has been tackled in http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101 , and the fact that it works in Java 8 is referred to as "generalized target type inference" - also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by user3580294 (+1) and in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455524/involing-generic-method-with-wildcards-does-not-compile#comment35957123_23455524): The reason is that the Java 7 type inference was not smart enough.

However, you may outsmart the type inference by omitting the wildcards while still keeping the desired flexibility:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TargetTypeInferenceTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Integer[] integers = { 3, 5, 8 };
        Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(integers));

        Double[] doubles = { 3.5, 5.5, 8.5 };
        Set<Double> s2 = new HashSet<Double>(Arrays.asList(doubles));

        Set<Number> res1 = union(s1, s1); // ->it does compile ;-)
        Set<Number> res2 = union(s1, s2); // ->it does compile ;-)
    }

    static <E, F extends E, G extends E> Set<E> union(Set<F> s1, Set<G> s2)
    {
        Set<E> result = new HashSet<E>(s1);
        result.addAll(s2);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's rather interesting that wildcards causes the compiler to give up whilst this doesn't. Wonder what causes the difference...

Comment: @user3580294 Yes, I'd really like to know this as well, because I'm desperately trying to become familiar with (and implement) type inference in the presence of sybtypes and generics. But I probably don't have to be ashamed when I say: I can't exaplain (at the moment) why this works, because the answer is hidden somewhere in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7 . Some related questions can be found here on StackOverflow, maybe you'll gain some insights from them.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Wrong answer. My mistake for misinterpreting.

Strangely enough, I get no compile errors in Java 8. You might need to tell the compiler what type `E` is directly. Try:

```
Set<Number> res1 = Main.<Number> union(s1, s1);
Set<Number> res2 = Main.<Number> union(s1, s2);
```

This worked for me using the Java 7 compiler.

My guess is that the compiler in previous versions of Java weren't smart enough to infer the proper type that would make the expression work, so as a result you're forced to tell it explicitly.

Comment: Sure.  But why is the parameter `E` not being inferred from context as `Number`?  In which case we'd effectively have `Set<Number> result = new HashSet<Number>(s1); result.addAll(s2);`, which should be fine.

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted the question. Fixed. I think.

Comment: Yes I know the above works. It looks however strange why without defining explicitly the type (to be returned), that cannot be infered and results in compilation error.

Comment: That's a failing of the pre-Java 8 compiler. You'll have to ask the writers why the above explicit bound couldn't be inferred prior to Java 8.